# How to write conditional for loop (if true loop through A, else loop through B)

Tags: c++, for-loop

I did some search but not find what I really want.

I have the scenario below: 
There are two containers with different type. E.g., one is  `vector<netIterator> A`, the other is `list<netIterator *> B`.

```
if (c) 
  for loop on A { doingSth using the current netIterator; } 
else
  for loop on B { doingSth using the current netIterator; }
```

doingSth now takes about 90 lines.

If I define it as an inline function, it cannot be inlined properly, and the runtime penalty is huge. 
(Adding more testing data: 
With non-inline function (which have about 12 arguments), the runtime is 300 seconds; using duplicated code, the runtime is about 15 seconds. 
Note that there are 1.5 million elements in the containers. )

Is there anyway to loop through A or B based on c efficiently without duplicating the code "doingSth"?

This is C++, and our company currently does not allow using of Boost library.

Thanks for any suggestions!

**{Update one day after I posted the question:**

With help of my colleague, I finally find the real reason for the runtime increase. It was not because the function not inlined, but **because two vector arguments of the function are passed by copy instead of by reference**. In each function call, the vectors are copied, constructed, grew and destroyed, which takes 300 seconds in 1.5 million iterations. After I fixed the problem, the runtime of using function is negligible.

The function is extracted by the IDE using "extract method" refactor, which I thought did it correctly, and did not check the argument list carefully, but in fact it did it awfully this time. I did use it before, and it did it well, but this time it is bad.

Thanks again for all answering and commenting on my question! This is my first question here, and I was impressed how fast I got the answer (few minutes!). I like all the answers and am glad to learn them from you!

**}**

Comment: Package that something in a lambda or full function.

Comment: I can't see why non-inlined function have huge runtime penalty

Comment: 90 lines of code should not be inlined. it could probably have no performance gain.

Comment: 89 typedefs and 1 pointer addition probably could make that happen.

Answer (score 2):

Sure there is a way:

```
void f(bool c, vector<T>& a, list<T>& b) {
    auto lambda = [&](T& t) {/* your magic here */}
    if(c)
        for(auto&& x : a)
            lambda(x);
    else
        for(auto&& x : b)
            lambda(x);
}
```

You can do the same with full functions equally well.

But before you complain about the huge runtime-penalty of calling a function vs. having it inlined, measure and compare!
(The same about binary-size for inlining, naturally.)

Comment: Yep !  and with `[&]` capture in case of the magic refers to some local variables.

Answer (score 0):

Hm. Well, I suppose you could do something like

```
template<typename Container, typename Deref>
void loop_over(Container &container, Deref deref) {
  for(auto &&element_raw : container) {
    auto &&element = deref(element_raw);

    // doSth with element
  }
}

...

if(c) {
  loop_over(A, [](netIterator &i) { return  i; });
} else {
  loop_over(B, [](netIterator *i) { return *i; });
}
```

That should give you two specialisations of the code.

I find it hard to believe, though, that failing to inline 90 lines of code has a huge performance impact. Have you measured this reliably?